# Get WM_LBUTTONDOWN message while ShellExecAndWait?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, jedi

In the Delphi IDE, create a `VCL Forms Application`. Then add a `TApplicationEvents` component and a `TButton` on the form. Then add these two event-handlers:

```
uses
  JclShell;

procedure TForm3.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
  begin
    Self.Caption := 'WM_LBUTTONDOWN';
  end
  else if Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONUP then
  begin
    Self.Caption := 'WM_LBUTTONUP';
  end
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  JclShell.ShellExecAndWait('C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe');
  Self.Caption := 'Notepad closed';
end;
```

Now click on the button. The following happens:

1. "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" appears on the form's title-bar.
2. "WM_LBUTTONUP" appears on the form's title-bar.
3. Notepad is executed.

Then click again on the button which starts another instance of Notepad BUT this time without writing anything on the form's title-bar.

Obviously, the program is stuck in `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait` which returns only when Notepad is closed. So when Notepad is closed any mouse-click again writes to the form's title-bar.

So we can see that while Notepad is running in `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait` everything in the program works normally: You could even make mathematical calculations while Notepad is running in `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait`. Only the `ApplicationEvents1Message` is not triggered while Notepad is running.

So how can I get a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message while Notepad is running in `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait`?

Comment: Do you need to know when notepad has closed?

Comment: Of course, I need to know.

Answer (score 0):

While `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait` is waiting for the spawned process to exit it uses following basic message pump:

```
while WaitForSingleObject(Sei.hProcess, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  repeat
    Msg.hwnd := 0;
    Res := PeekMessage(Msg, Sei.Wnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    if Res then
    begin
      TranslateMessage(Msg);
      DispatchMessage(Msg);
    end;
  until not Res;
CloseHandle(Sei.hProcess);
```

I say basic, because the looped part of the VCLs message pump looks like this:

```
 if PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) then
  begin
    Unicode := (Msg.hwnd = 0) or IsWindowUnicode(Msg.hwnd);
    if Unicode then
      MsgExists := PeekMessageW(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)
    else
      MsgExists := PeekMessageA(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

    if MsgExists then
    begin
      Result := True;
      if Msg.Message <> WM_QUIT then
      begin
        Handled := False;
        if Assigned(FOnMessage) then FOnMessage(Msg, Handled);
        if not IsPreProcessMessage(Msg) and not IsHintMsg(Msg) and
          not Handled and not IsMDIMsg(Msg) and
          not IsKeyMsg(Msg) and not IsDlgMsg(Msg) then
        begin
          TranslateMessage(Msg);
          if Unicode then
            DispatchMessageW(Msg)
          else
            DispatchMessageA(Msg);
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
  {$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
        if Assigned(FOnShutDown) then FOnShutDown(self);
        DoneApplication;
  {$IFEND}
        FTerminate := True;
      end;
    end;
```

The code line

`if Assigned(FOnMessage) then FOnMessage(Msg, Handled);`

is what will hand the message to your `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` via the `TMultiCaster` that `TApplicationEvents` has assigned to `Application.OnMessage`. This is not done in the JCL source. 
Additional issues *might be* that JCL is not UniCode aware regarding messages at this point and there is no handling for `WM_QUIT`.

What to do about this is depending on what you want to achieve, too. Why do you want to receive this messages in the first place?

I mean it is possible to alter the JCL source - if you are willing to do so - and to add `VCL.Forms` to the uses, and then call the event handler if assigned like the VCL does:

```
while WaitForSingleObject(Sei.hProcess, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  repeat
    Msg.hwnd := 0;
    Res := PeekMessage(Msg, Sei.Wnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    if Res then
    begin
      Handled := False;
      if Assigned(Application.OnMessage) then
        Application.OnMessage(Msg, Handled);
      if not Handled then
      begin
        TranslateMessage(Msg);
        DispatchMessage(Msg);
      end;
    end;
  until not Res;
CloseHandle(Sei.hProcess);
```

Or even call `Application.ProcessMessages`, to have the same message processing in place the VCL does:

```
while WaitForSingleObject(Sei.hProcess, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
CloseHandle(Sei.hProcess);
```

This is working, I could not see any side effects like commenters suggested. But before changing the JCL source in this way I would probably implement my own `ShellExecAndWait`. Depending on what you would like to achieve, the normal dispatching of messages should still work. So if your TFrom has e.g.

```
procedure WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
```

implemented, it should be called. This is, however, only the case if the message was directed at your form. If the button is clicked, the resulting messages will be directed to the button itself. You would need to implement your own descendant class then.

**Maybe a completely different suggestion?**

If your goal is to let certain controls not to be clicked while `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait` is waiting, and using message handling is your approach to make this possible, there might be other things you can try.

Why not **disable** them? This will also give the user a visible indication that clicking is a no-go.

```
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  try
    JclShell.ShellExecAndWait('C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe');
    Self.Caption := 'Notepad closed';
  finally
    Button1.Enabled := True;
  end;
```

If you are concerned about multiple controls create a `TAction`, assign it to every control you want to disable and disable all of them together with the `Enabled` property of the `TAction`.

Or, just **hide your form** while notepad.exe is opened?

```
  Hide;
  try
    JclShell.ShellExecAndWait('C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe');
    Self.Caption := 'Notepad closed';
  finally
    Show;
  end;
```

Or you could **remove the event handlers**:

```
var
  ATmpOnClick: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  ATmpOnClick := Button1.OnClick;
  Button1.OnClick := nil;
  try
    JclShell.ShellExecAndWait('C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe');
    Self.Caption := 'Notepad closed';
  finally
    Button1.OnClick := ATmpOnClick;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that this probably still won't work, because the `ShellExecAndWait()` loop is filtering messages by HWND, so `PeekMessage()` is not going to deliver messages for other HWNDs, like the button. A better solution is to move the `ShellExecuteAndWait()` call to a separate worker thread that notifies the main UI thread when notepad is closed

Comment: @nil, your solution to replace the message loop in JclShell (I created a replacement unit) seems to work. However, don't forget to declare the `Handled: Boolean;` variable in the `ShellExecAndWait` implementation. I still have to make a few tests, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user1580348 Remy might be right there. I did not remember the Wnd being set in the ShellExecuteInfo, need to look into that when having code available again.

Comment: My tests resulted in strange side effects: After `ShellExecAndWait` the normal message processing in the program did not work anymore.

Comment: @nil Yes, the `procedure WMLButtonDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;` seems to work after `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait`. But how can I set `Handled := True` in this procedure?

Comment: @user1580348 Take it with a grain of salt: do not call inherited in case you want that message not to be handled. I'll need to look into this more tomorrow, maybe I was to sure about some things ...I can for example not understand how my changed JCL code should work during waiting - especially keeping in mind what Remy remarked - but have side effects afterwards.

Comment: If you're going to add "forms" to JCL source I think you can directly call Application.ProcessMessage without removing the message and all of the application's processing will be carried out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, JCL is not setting the Wnd field of `TShellExecuteInfo`, so I assume the `PeekMessage` effectively called with a 0 Wnd, like in the VCLs message loop.

Comment: @nil: `JCL is not setting the Wnd field` - then it shouldn't be passing the `Wnd` to `PeekMessage()` at all. That is a bug waiting to happen of JCL ever decided in the future to update `ShellExecAndWait()` to fill in the `Wnd` for UI handling.

Comment: @user1580348: "*is the `JclShell.ShellExecAndWait` function thread-safe?*" - yes. It doesn't do anything tied to a particular thread (do note that a thread calling `ShellExecuteEx()` should call `CoInitialize/Ex()` first). That being said, calling `ShellExecAndWait()` in a thread means there won't be any UI messages to process (unless the thread has its own UI), so the code will just be running an empty `WaitForSingleProcess()` loop, taking up CPU time. Better to use a single call to `WaitForSingleProcess()` with an INFINITE timeout in that situation.

Comment: I think I've found the bug: https://i.imgur.com/aljFild.png Now it works perfectly!

Comment: @user1580348: If you are going to call `Application.ProcessMessages()` then *remove* the entire `PeekMessage()` loop altogether, since `ProcessMessages()` calls `PeekMessage()` for you (`Res` will always be `False`), eg: `while WaitForSingleObject(Sei.hProcess, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do Application.ProcessMessages;` That is all you need.

Comment: @user1580348: However, you should use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` instead. Call `ProcessMessages()` only when there are actually messages waiting to be processed, eg: `var Res: DWORD; ... repeat Res := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, Sei.hProcess, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT); if Res = WAIT_OBJECT_0+1 Then Application.ProcessMessages; until Res = WAIT_OBJECT_0;`

Comment: Could you write that at Pastebin please? Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to even wait at all? There's a lot of work here to solve the problem of waiting on the handle, when we don't know *why* we are waiting on `notepad.exe`.